# Illegal char <*> at index 98: C:\Users\xujian\project\duxapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\intermediates\library_*\*\jni

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-av

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\xujian\project\duxapp\node_modules\expo-av\android\build.gradle' line: 13
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-av'.

> Illegal char <*> at index 98: C:\Users\xujian\project\duxapp\node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\build\intermediates\library_**\jni

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

This problem occurs when packaging on windows

```json
    "react-native": "^0.69.5",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-brightness": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "~0.11.4",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.2.0",
    "expo-sensors": "~11.4.0",
```